# Removing ajax deleted data from $this->request->data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a edit() form for an expense claim. The expense claim is made up of lots of expenses. The form allows you to edit these expenses all on the same view. Each expense has a delete button which uses ajax to delete the record and remove the row from the edit form.

The ajax delete function works fine and deletes the record from the DB. The problem is that as this is a edit form all the data is already in $this->request->data so when you save your edits it recreates the records deleted by ajax. Normal edits work fine.

Is there a way to update the data in $this->request->data with the correct data in the form?

Am I missing something obvious?

I'm using cakephp 2.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the fields from the DOM (on a successful Ajax delete), they won't be part of $this->request->data when the form is submitted.

Comment: Really, then where is it getting the data to recreate the fields on save? I'll do some more debugging and post my findings. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Hi, I've been through everything again with fresh eyes and I still cant pinpoint whats causing the issue. The deleted expenses are recreated when the edit form is saved, which still makes me think $this->request->data is not been updated. Doing a debug($this->request->data) confirms that they are still present on the edit forms submit. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, deleting my browser cache fixed this issue....

Might help someone with the same issue.